# Redirect to index with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm starting to use ajax and I think I've lost a bit. I know there are many questions on this topic but I have not been able to find a solution.

I do not understand why it is not redirected to the index after making the request:

The code is this:

```
  var request = jQuery
    .ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      url: url_post_end,
      method: "GET",
      datatype: "json",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#End_btn").prop("disabled", true);
      },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      window.location = "index.html";
    });
```

Also tried with:

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url: url_post_end,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#End_btn").prop("disabled", true);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      window.location = "index.html";
    }
  });
```

And the json that it receives has the form of: {"imgname": "bla", "folder": "/ ssa /"}

Could someone tell me why the page is not redirected to the index?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not redirecting correctly. `window.location` is just an object reference to the current location of the browser. You need to use either `href` to simulate a link click, or `replace` to simulate an HTTP redirect. You should also be catching errors. In the event your ajax call falls, it will also fail to redirect and you wouldn't otherwise know why. Try this:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: url_post_end,
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#End_btn").prop("disabled", true);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        window.location.replace = "index.html";
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var request = jQuery
.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  url: url_post_end,
  method: "GET",
  datatype: "json",
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#End_btn").prop("disabled", true);
  },
})
.done(function(data) {
  window.location.href = "/"; //redirect to main page
  //or
  window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'; //Will take you to example.com.

});
```

You need to set `/` to redirect home **main** screen.